# Bar plot cutting off axis title

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw a bar plot with vertical axis labels and an axis title.

The script below makes the graph but it cuts off the x-axis label/title. Even if I try to make the picture bigger on my screen it still is cut off a bit. Also when I run this, I have to run it twice. The first time I get error about the fontdict property, but the next time it works.

Anyone know how to not make it cut that off? Also I am just saving the one that pops up on the screen as the saving is not working for some reason.

Thanks!

```
import numpy
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pylab as pylab
import matplotlib.pyplot
import pdb
from collections import Counter


phenos = [128, 20, 0, 144, 4, 16, 160, 136, 192, 128, 20, 0, 4, 16, 144, 130, 136, 132, 22, 
128, 160, 4, 0, 36, 132, 136, 130, 128, 22, 4, 0, 144, 160, 130, 132, 
128, 4, 0, 136, 132, 68, 130, 192, 8, 128, 4, 0, 20, 22, 132, 144, 192, 130, 2, 
128, 4, 0, 132, 20, 136, 144, 192, 64, 130, 128, 4, 0, 144, 132, 192, 20, 16, 136, 
128, 4, 0, 130, 160, 132, 192, 2,  128, 4, 0, 132, 68, 160, 192, 36, 64, 
128, 4, 0, 136, 192, 8, 160, 36, 128, 4, 0, 22, 20, 144, 132, 160,
128, 4, 0, 132, 20, 192, 144, 160, 68, 64, 128, 4, 0, 132, 160, 144, 136, 192, 68, 20]



from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from operator import itemgetter


c = Counter(phenos).items()
c.sort(key=itemgetter(1))

font = {'family' : 'sanserif',
        'color'  : 'black',
        'weight' : 'normal',
        'size'   : 22,
        }

font2 = {'family' : 'sansserif',
        'color'  : 'black',
        'weight' : 'normal',
        'size'   : 18,
        }
labels, values = zip(*c)
labels = ("GU", "IT", "AA", "SG", "A, IGI", "A, SG", "GU, A, AA", "D, GU", "D, IT", "A, AA", "D, IGI", "D, AA", "192", "D, A", "D, H", "H", "A")
pylab.show()
pylab.draw()

indexes = np.arange(0, 2*len(labels), 2)
width = 2
plt.bar(indexes, values, width=2, color="blueviolet")
plt.xlabel("Phenotype identifier", fontdict=font)
plt.ylabel("Number of occurances in top 10 \n phenotypes for cancerous tumours", fontdict=font)
#plt.title("Number of occurances for different phenotypes \n in top 10 subclones of a tumour", fontdict=font2)
plt.xticks(indexes + width * 0.5, labels, rotation='vertical', fontdict=font2)
plt.figure(figsize=(8.0, 7.0))
pictureFileName2 = "..\\Stats\\"  + "Phenos2.png"
pylab.savefig(pictureFileName2, dpi=800)


#fig.set_size_inches(18.5,10.5)
#plt.savefig('test2png.png',dpi=100)
```

Comment: May I ask why you've imported `numpy` and `Counter` twice and also imported both `pylab` and `plt` from matplotlib? O.o

Comment: Cutting and pasting headers from various scripts and then forgetting and adding them back at the point of use :)

Comment: Unfortunately I could not replicate your error, both using `show` and `savefig` I get a figure with no text being cut off.

Comment: @Ffisegydd, that's `backend` dependent. For one, in `ipython notebook` inline mode, it will never be a problem.

Comment: @CTZhu I never thought about backend dependency. I was using the standard matplotlib backend and not using ipython, unfortunately the OP did not give any details.

Answer (score 3):

Three problems:

1, It is not true that the first time you run the code it doesn't work and the second time it does. The reason is that you call `.show()` before making the plot. The 1st time you run the code, the code stopped at where the except error message indicates. The 2nd time, `.show()` gets executed first and the partially made plot from the previous run now show up.

2, `fontdict=font2` etc is not necessary and in fact wrong. You just need `**font2` etc.

3, The truncated tick labels. There are just about many different ways to do it, but the basic idea is to increase the area of white space around the plot, alternatives are:

```
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.35, top=0.7) #adjusting the plotting area

plt.tight_layout() #may raise an exception, depends on which backend is in use

plt.savefig('test.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches = 0.0) #use bbox and pad, if you only want to change the saved figure.
```

Comment: Thanks for all of the information. Both of the last two suggestions are giving errors, and the top just gives me a tiny graph with giant text, none of which is readable. I tried just changing the graph so the text was smaller but now I'm getting like a "double graph"... I will post below

Comment: I updated the question and code here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23499445/bar-plot-double-plotting-python-matplotlib Thanks again